# RoR - Angular Error: Unknown provider: mWebSrvcProvider <- mWebSrvc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

My Angular code works just fine on it's own, but once I place it inside of a RoR project, then I receive the error that you see listed in the title -

```
//all the common / models are added to this.. so we can re-use across apps
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngResource', 'ngSanitize', 'ngCookies', 'ui.bootstrap']);

//app for all flows
var mWebApp = angular.module('mWebApp', ['mainApp', 'mWebApp.mWebSrvc', 'mWebApp.mWebCtrl'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
          templateUrl: 'angular/views/index.html',
          controller: 'mWebCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
        });
}]);

var mGlobolJson = [];

var mWebCtrl = function($rootScope, $scope, $timeout, $location, mWebSrvc) {
    $scope.nav_tpl = 'angular/views/nav.html';
    $scope.footer_tpl = 'angular/views/footer.html';
    $scope.Index = null;

$scope.loc = "";
$scope.loc = $location.path();

$scope.go = function(hash){
    $scope.loc = $location.path();
    $location.path(hash);
}

mWebSrvc.getCustomers(function(data){
    $scope.items = data;
    mGlobolJson = data;
});

$scope.doNothing = function(){}

$scope.myEnlargeImage = function(someParamComing){
    var newWin = window.open("", name="_blank", "width=1270,height=952,toolbar=0,status=1,menubar=0,top=0,left=0,location=0,outerWidth=1270,outerHeight=952");
    var htmlVar = "";
    htmlVar += "<html><body bgcolor='#666'><img id='myLargerImage' style='position: absolute; top: -5px; left: -5px;' src="+someParamComing+" /></body></html>";
    newWin.document.write(htmlVar);
}
}

mainApp.controller('mWebCtrl', mWebCtrl);

var mWebSrvc = function($http, $log) {

this.getCustomers = function() {
    $http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : 'http://localhost:3000/api/customers/'
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $log.log('Done');
        angular.forEach(data, function(c) {
            $log.log(c.Title);
        });
        customers = data;
        return customers;
    });     
};

this.insertCustomer = function(Title, h1, Comments, Comments2, download_coupon) {
    var topID = customers.length + 1;
    customers.push({
        id : topID,
        Title : Title,
        h1 : h1,
        Comments : Comments,
        Comments2 : Comments2,
        download_coupon : download_coupon
    });
};

this.getCustomer = function(id) {

};

this.deleteCustomer = function(id) {

};

}    
mainApp.service('mWebSrvc', mWebSrvc);
```

The file structure for the RoR project is as follows:

```
app> assets> javascript> mAngular> mWeb.js
app> assets> javascript> mAngular> scripts> services> mWebSrvc.js
app> assets> javascript> mAngular> scripts> controllers> mWebCtrl.js
```

I have even tried to name the scripts directory "scripts" to insure that it loads after mWeb.js, as well as controllers to insure that mWebCtrl.js loads after mWebSrvc.js, but to no avail.

I have used the directory structure for countless Angular projects, which is able to GET or POST to a JSON file, without issue.

Why would this same code work in a stand alone Angular and Not in RoR?

Comment: I believe I know why and I can't believe it did not dawn on me before, but I have to rewrite all of this in coffeescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, once I converted all my Angular to coffeescript, then it worked perfectly with RoR

```
    @mWebApp.config(['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) ->
    $routeProvider
      .when('/customers', {
        templateUrl: '../templates/customers/index.html',
        controller: 'mWebCtrl'
      })
     .when('/customers/:Title', {
        templateUrl: '../templates/customers/show.html',
        controller: 'mWebShowCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        templateUrl: '../templates/home.html',
        controller: 'mWebCtrl'
      });
]);

@mWebApp.controller 'mWebCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', ($scope, $location, $http) ->
  $scope.customers = []
  $http.get('./api/customers').success((data) ->
    $scope.customers = data
  )
  $scope.viewCustomer = ((Title) ->
    $location.url "/customers/#{Title}"
  )
]

@mWebApp.controller 'mWebShowCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', ($scope, $http, $routeParams) ->
  $http.get("./api/customers/#{$routeParams.Title}").success((data) ->
    $scope.customer = data
  )
]

@mWebApp.directive 'customerTitle', [ ->
  restrict: 'E',
  template: '<h1>{{ customer.0.Title }}</h1>'
]

@mWebApp.directive 'customerH1', [ ->
  restrict: 'E',
  template: '<h2>{{ customer.0.h1 }}</h2>'
]

@mWebApp.directive 'customerComments', [ ->
  restrict: 'E',
  template: '<li><p>{{ customer.0.Comments }}</p></li>'
]

@mWebApp.directive 'customerComments2', [ ->
  restrict: 'E',
  template: '<li><p>{{ customer.0.Comments2 }}</p></li>'
]

@mWebApp.directive 'customerDownloadGallery', [ ->
  restrict: 'E',
  template: '<li>{{ customer.0.download_gallery }}</li>'
]

@mWebApp.directive 'customerCreatedAt', [ ->
  restrict: 'E',
  template: '<li><p>{{ customer.0.created_at }}</p></li>'
]

@mWebApp.directive 'customerUpdatedAt', [ ->
  restrict: 'E',
  template: '<li><p>{{ customer.0.updated_at }}</p></li>'
]

@mWebApp.service 'mWebSrvc', ['$scope', ($scope) ->

]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this problem is caused by minification. Rails minifies these files and dependency injection stops working because minification replaces argument names in function with shorter names (like a, b, c, etc.). To make Angular work when minified, you need to write code in a specific manner. For example:

```
app.controller('myCOntroller', function($scope) {
});
```

should be written like this:

```
app.controller('myCOntroller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
}]);
```

This enables angular to do dependency injection properly.
In your case, you have:

```
var mWebCtrl = function($rootScope, $scope, $timeout, $location, mWebSrvc) {
....
};
```

And your controller definition should be as follows:

```
mainApp.controller('mWebCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$timeout', '$location', 'mWebSrvc', mWebCtrl]);
```

There is also alternative way for doing this:

```
mWebCtrl.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$timeout', '$location', 'mWebSrvc']
mainApp.controller('mWebCtrl', mWebCtrl);
```

Also, for the service:

```
mainApp.service('mWebSrvc', ['$http', '$log', mWebSrvc]);
```

You can read more about this issue [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05).

Comment: Thanks for the info, but converting to coffeescript allowed everything to work with RoR